# I am trying to join three tables and concat 2 different column into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, for-xml-path

I am trying to join three tables and concatenate 2 different columns into multiple rows.  I have four columns of data when I run a regular query with multiple filenames and multiple phone numbers.  I want to get rid of the duplicates that result with the query.

I would like to have the id not duplicated with the different filenames concatenated into another column for id separated by commas.  The same thing should be true with all the phone numbers concatenated into one row with the corresponding id and separated by comma.

I found some examples using xml path, but they were with only two tables and two columns.

Below I have the three tables, the query I have so far, and the query I wish to have.  Does anyone know how to do nested xml paths while joining tables?

Table:  IPMFILE
ID                     FILENAME
10000.000       10000_45109.doc
10001.000       10001_45115.docx
10002.000       10002_47752.doc
10002.000       10002_45119.doc
10003.000       10003_45123.doc
10004.000       10004_45128.docx
10004.000       10004_45183.docx

Table:   Persons
ID                         CITY
10000.000       Elkins Park
10001.000       4504 St. James Drive Plano
10002.000       Fort Collins
10003.000       Bound Brook
10004.000       Downers Grove

Table:   Phone
ID                     phone
10000.000       215-7177179
10001.000       972-6187143
10002.000       970-4439376
10003.000       Home 732-3693106
10004.000       C 630-4648539
10004.000       H 630-9681673

```
SELECT PERSONS.ID, impfile.FILENAME, phonenumbers.phone, PERSONS.CITY 
FROM IMPFILE, Persons, Phonenumbers WHERE impfile.ID=Persons.ID 
AND phonenumbers.id=persons.id AND PERSONS.ID 
BETWEEN 10000 AND 10004 order by person
```

Result of Query
ID                      FILENAME                      phone                            CITY
10000.000   10000_45109.doc             215-7177179                Elkins Park
10001.000      10001_45115.docx         972-6187143                4504 St. James Drive Plano
10002.000      10002_47752.doc,         970-4439376                Fort Collins
10002.000      10002_45119.doc          970-4439376                Fort Collins
10003.000      10003_45123.doc             Home 732-3693106             Bound Brook
10004.000      10004_45128.docx       C 630-4648539                Downers Grove
10004.000      10004_45183.docx       C 630-4648539                Downers Grove
10004.000      10004_45128.docx       H 630-9681673                Downers Grove
10004.000      10004_45183.docx       H 630-9681673                Downers Grove

Desired Query with Filename Concatenated for each id and Phone number concatenated for each id and duplicates removed
ID                                FILENAME                                                                          phone                
                          CITY
10000.000              10000_45109.doc                                215-7177179              
           Elkins Park
10001.000        10001_45115.docx                  
                 972-6187143 
                    4504 St. James Drive Plano
10002.000          10002_47752.doc, 10002_45119.doc         970-4439376                       Fort Collins
10003.000        10003_45123.doc               
                     Home 732-3693106                    Bound Brook
10004.000        10004_45128.docx, 10004_45183.docxC      630-4648539,H 630-9681673       Downers Grove

I found this on another post:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ThisTable 
   OUTER APPLY (SELECT (SELECT SomeField + ' ' AS [data()] 
                        FROM   SomeTable 
                        WHERE  SomeTable.ID = ThisTable.ID 
                        FOR XML PATH ('')) AS ConcatenatedSomeField) A 
   OUTER APPLY (SELECT (SELECT SomeField2 + ' ' AS [data()] 
                        FROM   SomeTable 
                        WHERE  SomeTable.ID = ThisTable.ID 
                        FOR XML PATH ('')) AS ConcatenatedSomeField2) B 
   OUTER APPLY (SELECT (SELECT SomeField3 + ' ' AS [data()] 
                        FROM   SomeTable 
                        WHERE  SomeTable.ID = ThisTable.ID 
                        FOR XML PATH ('')) AS ConcatenatedSomeField3) C
```

Comment: yes this example which you found should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. 
You need to add WHERE clause here. Also I found there are some mismatches in your provided code: like ORDER BY person - there is no such column in provided tables.

```
SELECT p.ID
  , imp.FILENAME
  , pn.phone
  , p.CITY 
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT ID,
              STUFF(( SELECT ',' + IPM.FILENAME AS [text()]
                      FROM IPMFILE AS IPM
                      WHERE IPM.ID = I.ID
                      FOR XML PATH('') 
                        ), 1, 1, '' )
            AS [Filename]
      FROM IPMFILE AS I
      ) as imp 
INNER JOIN Persons as p
  ON imp.ID=p.ID 
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ID,
              STUFF(( SELECT ',' + p2.phone AS [text()]
                      FROM Phonenumbers AS p2
                      WHERE p2.ID = p1.ID
                      FOR XML PATH('') 
                        ), 1, 1, '' )
            AS [phone]
      FROM Phonenumbers AS p1
      ) as pn
  ON pn.id=p.id
ORDER BY p.id
```

a bit explanation about sub-select. With this part we collect rows into one row by ID:

```
SELECT ',' + p2.phone AS [text()]
FROM Phonenumbers AS p2
WHERE p2.ID = p1.ID 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

and after that we use function `STUFF` to remove last comma from collected row.

Also you can find example here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9fc6/17